# Is there a ServerCloseEvent in the Bukkit API?

Tags: java, events, minecraft, bukkit

I am developing a Bukkit plugin, and I would like to save the configuration file when the server closes.

Is there an event like `ServerCloseEvent` which I can use?

Comment: You could try a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `onDisable` in your `JavaPlugin` subclass to run any code before your plugin gets disabled. Note that your plugin getting disabled does not necessarily mean that the server is shutting down, a /reload or another plugin can also cause your plugin to unload.

Answer (score 2):

There is no event for the server closing, but there is a method in the `JavaPlugin` class, which should be extended by your `Main` class:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

  @Override
  public void onDisable(){
    //called when the plugin (and therefor the server) is disabled.
  }

}
```

To save the configuration file in your class that extends `JavaPlugin`, you can call

```
this.saveConfig();
```

An example of code in your `Main` class (the one that extends `JavaPlugin`) that would save the configuration file when the server is disabled/stopped would be:

```
@Override
public void onDisable(){
  //Server has been shut down, so save the config file
  this.saveConfig();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should override the `onDisable()` method from the `JavaPlugin` superclass instead.
See [onEnable() and onDisable()](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial#onEnable.28.29_and_onDisable.28.29) in the official plugin tutorial.

```
public class Example extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Plugins are enabled when the server starts or when a reload is performed
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // Plugins are disabled when the server shuts down or when a reload is performed
        // Save the config here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, however you can run code when your plugin is disabled by implementing the `onDisable()` method in your main class.

Answer (score 0):

Their is no such thing as a ServerCloseEvent. However, if you want to save the config files when the server stop's you could put it under the `onDisable` method in your main class. I would also strongly suggest that if your adding something into a config when someone joins, disconnects, dies, runs a command or such that you save it right away. I say this beacuse the server isn't going to run the onDisable if the server decide's to crash.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using the onDisable method is that it only occurs once this specific plugin is disabled. Say the plugin was disabled via a command, or by other methods. Your plugin would think the server is turning off, but it isn't.